# Physics category struct in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, swift, uint32

I have been making a game using Sprite Kit and its physics and met this struct in tutorial:

```
struct PhysicsCategory
{
    static let None: UInt32 = 0
    static let All: UInt32 = UInt32.max
    static let Player: UInt32 = 0b10
    static let Obstacle: UInt32 = 0b11
}
```

Can anyone tell me what means 0b01 etc. and how to make a new constant here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hexa, that is, a 16-base number

0b11 in hexa is

0 * 16^3 + 11 * 16^2 + 1 * 16^1 + 1 * 16^0 = 2816 + 16 + 1 = 2833

In hexa, numbers like 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 are represented by letters, such as a, b, c, d, e, f

Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Hexadecimal) for more info.